# Angular component as a grid item

Tags: css, angular, css-grid, angular-components

When I transform a raw HTML grid item into an angular component, it stops behaving correctly, as if it was not aware of the grid anymore. Why and how to correct it ?

The code working

```html
<div class="grid-with-various-col">
    <div class="grid-item-spanning-various-col">
        <!-- This div is correctly displayed in the grid -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The Angular component "my-comp"

```html
<div class="grid-item-spanning-various-col">
    <!-- Same div as previously -->
</div>
```

The code not working

```html
<div class="grid-item-spanning-various-col">
    <my-comp>
        <!-- This comp is not correctly displayed in the grid -->
    </my-comp>
</div>
```

JsFiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/oLuax49n/2/

Comment: Is not correctly displayed or has a different behavior? it could be something with your styles classes or it could be the functionality of your component, it could be so many things, we need more information.

Comment: Show the rendered output of the Angular code so we can compare to the original. If the output is the same the behavior will be the same. Is your CSS encapsulated so it's not being applied as expected?

Comment: try `:host {display: contents}` for the component

Comment: @Andrei that was it, thank you. A drawback is that when inspecting the DOM and hovering the HTLM line for <my-comp>, it is not highlighted in the page anymore. I have to go one node below for the highlight to kick in. From what I understand from your solution it seems normal, as I tell the DOM to not consider <my-comp> as nested anymore, as if the wrapper did not exist. Still a shame.

I added a JsFiddle with the initial issue for people to understand better. I am very surprise I did not find more topics about this, considering it must be a very common pattern with a not so obvious solution.